# Why arrays do not print whole table?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int d,m;
    int districts=3;
        int months = 12;
    double sales[districts][months];

    for (d=0 ; d < districts; d++)
    {
        for(m=0; m< months; m++)
        {
            cout << "Enter sales for District " << d+1 << ":" << " and Month " << m+1 << ":   ";
            cin >> sales[districts][months];
        }
    }


    cout << "\n\n\n";
    cout << setw(40) << "Months\n";
    cout << setw(26) << "1       2        3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11     12\n";
    for (d=0; d < districts ; d++)
    {
            cout << "District " << d+1;
        for(m=0; m< months; m++)
        {
        cout << ": " << sales[districts][months];
         } 
    }

    return 0;

}
```

This code after running takes only two input values from user and after that a window appear displaying message `a problem caused the program to stop working correctly`. 
There are no compilation errors and I am unable to find the problem. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: What input did you provide?

Comment: I entered double type numbers e.g 789.98 and 788.07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this: `cin >> sales[districts][months];` to this: `cin >> sales[d][m];`

Also, this: `cout << ": " << sales[districts][months];` to this: `cout << ": " << sales[d][m];`.

The term `sales[districts][months]` refers to a particular element `sales[3][12]`, which also happens to be out of bounds for the 2-d array.

Answer (score 2):

You use variables `d` and `m` as counter-variables for your loops, but inside the loops you use the maximum value for both of them (`districts` and `months`) instead of `d` and `m`.

Answer (score 0):

The reading loop is repeatedly reading a value to `sales[districts][months]`, i.e. to `sales[3][12]`, which - since array indexing starts at zero in all dimensions, doesn't exist.    That gives undefined behaviour.

The output loops are repeatedly outputting the same value, which also gives undefined behaviour.

A common symptom (but not the only possible one) of undefined behaviour is abnormal program termination - and you are seeing an example of that.

There is also the wrinkle that

```
int districts=3;
int months = 12;
double sales[districts][months];
```

involves a variable length array (VLA) which is a feature of C (from the 1999 C standard or later) but is not valid C++.   If that construct works for you, your compiler supports a non-standard extension.